# Kali Linux: cannot login to desktop

Tags: kali-linux

I was running Kali Linux 2.0 Sansa. I did the Kali Linux
`apt-get update` && `apt-get upgrade`

To upgrade to Kali 2.0 rolling edition now I cannot log in
The user name and password still work because if I do 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>.   They work on the command line.

But in GUI it just loop over and over, keeps on asking for user name and password.

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try is rule out the useraccount settings as a cause. Since those are generally stored in your home directory (`/home/you`), the fastest way would be to login on another screen, make yourself `root`, rename your original home directory to another name (`mv /home/you /home/you.old`) and recreate your home directory (`mkdir /home/you ;  cp -r /etc/skel /home/you ; chown -R you:you /home/you`). Another possibility would be to create another new user and try that.

Comment: I tried creating a user....userad  -m user1 ....usermod -a -G sudo user1...then

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer by @JdeHaan worked for me. You can even use the solution without creating new `/home/you` directory (the first two steps).

```
cp -r /etc/skel /home/you ; chown -R you:you /home/you
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is an answer. It feels more like a comment on another question

Comment: The disadvantage of this approach is that you lose any configuration you had that’s overwritten by files in `/etc/skel`. Creating a separate home avoids that — you can compare the configurations after checking that a basic setup works.

Comment: @StephenKitt you don't necessarily lose the configuration because this isn't a replace it's an overwrite of the selection of files in `/etc/skel`. Typically nothing in `~/.config` is likely to be reset

Comment: @roaima yes, that’s why I wrote “that’s overwritten by files in `/etc/skel`”. In fact, given that all the DE configuration will be left as-is, this is unlikely to help much in the scenario given in the question.